# How to solve nan loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

## Problem

I'm running a Deep Neural Network on the MNIST where the loss defined as follow:

`cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, label))`

The program seems to run correctly until I get a nan loss in the 10000+ th minibatch. Sometimes, the program runs correctly until it finished. I think `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` is giving me this error.
This is strange, because the code just contains `mul` and `add` operations.

## Possible Solution

Maybe I can use:

```
if cost == "nan":
  optimizer = an empty optimizer 
else:
  ...
  optimizer = real optimizer
```

But I cannot find the type of `nan`. How can I check a variable is `nan` or not?

How else can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check implementation of "tf.add_check_numerics_ops", that adds `Assert` ops to every tensor to make sure there are no nans, so you can use whatever it uses to check for nanness

Comment: I am new to tensorflow, when I use "tf.add_check_numerics_ops", it brings me an error "tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: All inputs to node model/CheckNumerics_254 must be from the same frame." Did I use it in a wrong way?

Comment: I just meant that you can look in implementation of `add_check_numerics_ops` to see which op determines if a variable is NaN, and use that op

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow Nan loss reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050397/tensorflow-nan-loss-reasons)

Answer (score 9):

I find a similar problem here [TensorFlow cross_entropy NaN problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug/33713196#33713196)

Thanks to the author user1111929

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits => -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
```

is actually a horrible way of computing the cross-entropy. In some samples, certain classes could be excluded with certainty after a while, resulting in y_conv=0 for that sample. That's normally not a problem since you're not interested in those, but in the way cross_entropy is written there, it yields 0*log(0) for that particular sample/class. Hence the NaN.

Replacing it with

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv + 1e-10))
```

Or

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y_conv,1e-10,1.0)))
```

Solved nan problem.

Answer (score 8):

The reason you are getting NaN's is most likely that somewhere in your cost function or softmax you are trying to take a log of zero, which is not a number. But to answer your specific question about detecting NaN, Python has a built-in capability to test for NaN in the math module. For example:

```
import math
val = float('nan')
val
if math.isnan(val):
    print('Detected NaN')
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # Break into debugger to look around
```

Comment: log(0) = -Infinity as far as I know

Answer (score 7):

Check your learning rate. The bigger your network, more parameters to learn. That means you also need to decrease the learning rate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your code or data. But `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` should be stable with a valid probability distribution (more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)). I assume your data does not meet this requirement. An analogous problem was also discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2327). Which would lead you to either:

1. Implement your own `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` function, e.g. try ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2327)):

   ```
   epsilon = tf.constant(value=0.00001, shape=shape)
   logits = logits + epsilon
   softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
   cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(labels * tf.log(softmax), reduction_indices=[1])
   ```
2. Update your data so that it does have a valid probability distribution

Comment: I use the standard mnist dataset, I think its probability distribution is valid.

Comment: Why the epsilon is add to logits rather than softmax?

Comment: `epsilon` is added to the logits so that the sum of the resulting softmax is still 1, but cannot contain zeros either (these result in NaN). It's very strange that you have this problem with the standard mnist dataset...
Could you check what happens if you use this new `cross_entropy` function? If that doesn't work, you probably have to look at the actual logits.

Comment: Hi, I just found a similar question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712178/tensorflow-nan-bug/33713196#33713196) in which case the cross_entropy was adjusted with `clipping`. Although here he started with a very simple implementation of cross_entropy,  instead of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. 
BTW, did you get it to work now?