# Neural Network Gives a Loss of Nan When Training

Tags: python, pandas, keras, neural-network, regression

I'm training a Keras neural net in Python. When the model is training, the loss is NAN. I can't figure out why this would be. There are no NAN values in the input. Here is the code.

```
    def train_model(self, epochs, batch_size, verbose=1, layer_sizes=[], activation_function='relu',
                    loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam'):
        layer_sizes = list(layer_sizes)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(self.features.shape[1], input_dim=self.features.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal',
                        activation=activation_function))
        for i in range(len(layer_sizes)):
            model.add(Dense(layer_sizes[i], kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation_function))
        model.add(Dense(self.targets.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation_function))
        model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)
        model.fit(self.X_train, self.Y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, batch_size=batch_size)
        self.model = model
```

with the following output

```
   128/857336 [..............................] - ETA: 58:15 - loss: nan
   384/857336 [..............................] - ETA: 21:36 - loss: nan
   640/857336 [..............................] - ETA: 14:12 - loss: nan
   896/857336 [..............................] - ETA: 11:01 - loss: nan
```

and it continue on further

Testing for nans is here

```
print(df.isnull().values.any())

False
```

Here is the link to a CSV with sample data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJqcEmTQ24WebelyLRkGOuPFlSUJt92c/view?usp=sharing

and here is the constructor code

```
        if data_file == '':
            self.engine = create_engine(
                'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(Model.user, Model.password, Model.host, Model.port,
                                                     Model.database))
            data = [chunk for chunk in
                    pd.read_sql('select * from "{}"'.format(Model.table), self.engine, chunksize=200000)]
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=data[0].columns)
            for datum in data:
                df = pd.concat([df, datum])
            df.to_hdf('Cleaned_Data.h5', key='df', mode='w')
        else:
            df = pd.read_hdf(data_file)
        df = df.fillna(0)
        df = df.head(1000)
        df.to_csv('Minimum_sample.csv')
        print(df.isnull().values.any())
        columns = list(df.columns)
        misc_data, self.targets, self.features = columns[0:5], columns[6:9], columns[5:6]
        misc_data.extend(columns[9:10])
        misc_data.extend(columns[12:13])
        misc_data.extend(columns[15:16])
        self.targets.extend(columns[10:12])
        self.targets.extend(columns[13:15])
        self.targets.extend(columns[16:26])
        self.features.extend(columns[73:470])
        df = df[misc_data + self.targets + self.features]
        self.targets = df[self.targets].values
        self.features = df[self.features].values
        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.Y_train, self.Y_test = train_test_split(self.features, self.targets,
                                                                                test_size=test_split_size)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: model.train_model(1, 128, layer_sizes=[217]) is the line of code that is called. Do you need some sample data as well?

Comment: _Do you need some sample data as well?_ I think that should be covered on the page I linked.

Comment: I added sample data to the question as well as the class constructor. The only difference is the data I'm using is stored in an h5 file while the data supplied is a CSV. Let me know if there is anything else!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050397/deep-learning-nan-loss-reasons

Comment: The learning rate is not the issue since the loss never diverges. Furthermore,this is not a classifier. Finally, the question checks for NAN and the only activation function is RELU.

Comment: Most likely your network is divergent. Try lowering your learning rate.

Comment: The default learning rate with Adam is already 0.001 which is quite low.

Answer (score 0):

You need to standardize your input in some way. Try this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scalerx = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(self.X_train)
self.X_train = scalerx.transform(self.X_train)
self.X_test = scalerx.transform(self.X_test)
```