# proper input and output shape of a keras Sequential model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, data-science

I am trying to run a [Keras](https://keras.io/) sequential model but can't get the right shape for the model to train on.

I reshaped `x` and `y` to:

```
x = x.reshape(len(x), 500)
y = y.reshape(len(y), 500)
```

Currently, both the input shape and output shape are:

```
(9766, 500)
(9766, 500)
```

The dataset consists of 9766 inputs and 9766 outputs respectively. Each input is a single array of 500 values and each output is also an array of 500 values.

So here is one single input array:

```
[0.99479668 0.99477965 0.99484778 0.99489887 0.99483926 0.99451565
 0.99458378 0.99457526 0.99453268 0.99468597 0.99466042 0.99449862
 0.99453268 0.99454971 0.99463487 0.99461784 0.99451565 0.99463487
 0.99467745 0.99502661 0.99480519 0.99493294 0.99493294 0.99522248
 0.99526506 0.99528209 0.99527358 0.99515435 0.99529913 0.99488184
 0.99508623 0.99512881 0.99522248 0.99497552 0.9954439  0.99554609
 0.99581861 0.99573345 0.9957079  0.99626144 0.99626144 0.99592932
 0.99558867 0.99541835 0.99524803 0.99586119 0.99601448 0.99588674
 0.99584416 0.99559719 0.995495   0.99520545 0.99552055 0.99510326
 0.9951799  0.99560571 0.99561422 0.99541835 0.99586119 0.995759
 0.9957079  0.99583564 0.9959208  0.99578454 0.99604854 0.99612519
 0.99609112 0.99630402 0.9961337  0.99672983 0.99655099 0.99643176
 0.99643176 0.99648286 0.99649138 0.99645731 0.99670428 0.99654247
 0.99647435 0.99607409 0.99589525 0.99600596 0.99596338 0.99621035
 0.99633809 0.99632106 0.99583564 0.99581009 0.99574196 0.9959719
 0.99557164 0.99567383 0.99572493 0.9958697  0.99568235 0.9959208
 0.99598893 0.99620183 0.99611667 0.99620183 0.9959719  0.9957079
 0.99612519 0.99558867 0.99569938 0.99518842 0.99553758 0.99552055
 0.99576751 0.99577603 0.99583564 0.99602299 0.99630402 0.99637215
 0.99701937 0.99701086 0.99731744 0.99700234 0.99696828 0.99668725
 0.99703641 0.99725782 0.99684054 0.99605706 0.99608261 0.99581861
 0.9958697  0.99583564 0.99566532 0.99585267 0.99566532 0.99604003
 0.99540984 0.99473707 0.995231   0.99441346 0.9942261  0.99397914
 0.99367256 0.99409836 0.99415797 0.99420907 0.99398765 0.99356185
 0.99382585 0.99428571 0.9945412  0.99444752 0.99436236 0.99404726
 0.9938003  0.99424313 0.99483074 0.99474558 0.99457526 0.99457526
 0.99465191 0.99466042 0.99467745 0.99448158 0.99454971 0.99479668
 0.994703   0.99455823 0.99472855 0.99507771 0.99529913 0.99515435
 0.99525655 0.99621886 0.99586119 0.99576751 0.9962359  0.99614222
 0.99723228 0.99685757 0.99680647 0.99689163 0.99644028 0.99701937
 0.99675538 0.99637215 0.99614222 0.99628699 0.9964488  0.99641473
 0.99652544 0.99652544 0.99664467 0.99698531 0.99712157 0.99703641
 0.99799872 0.99859485 0.99876517 0.99950607 0.99902065 0.99891846
 0.99804982 0.99839898 0.99857782 0.99850117 0.99891846 0.99912284
 0.99919097 0.99919949 0.99896956 0.99896104 0.99877369 0.99898659
 0.99918246 0.99890994 0.9990462  0.99895252 0.99885033 0.99871407
 0.99871407 0.99871407 0.99864594 0.99854375 0.9983564  0.9985693
 0.99870556 0.99868001 0.9987822  0.99877369 0.99900362 0.99882478
 0.99896956 0.99885885 0.99880775 0.99890994 0.99906323 0.99908026
 0.9990462  0.99921652 0.99920801 0.99936129 0.99937833 0.99943794
 0.99935278 0.99943794 0.99967639 0.99956568 0.99960826 0.99962529
 0.99942942 0.99940387 0.9992591  0.99908878 0.99912284 0.99913988
 0.99905472 0.99914839 0.99913136 0.99933575 0.99935278 0.99929317
 0.99931871 0.99905472 0.99965084 0.99995742 1.         0.99962529
 0.999472   0.99939536 0.99932723 0.99929317 0.99931871 0.99931871
 0.99950607 0.99953162 0.99942942 0.99919097 0.99902917 0.99913988
 0.99915691 0.9990462  0.9990973  0.99923355 0.99940387 0.99954865
 0.99958271 0.99940387 0.99943794 0.99928465 0.9990973  0.99905472
 0.99915691 0.99921652 0.99913988 0.99913136 0.99912284 0.9992591
 0.99916542 0.99917394 0.99918246 0.99906323 0.99905472 0.99907175
 0.99901214 0.9990462  0.99913988 0.9990462  0.9990462  0.99880775
 0.99890994 0.99868852 0.99868852 0.99889291 0.99896956 0.99886736
 0.99932723 0.99943794 0.99932723 0.99931871 0.99931871 0.99921652
 0.99874814 0.99871407 0.99915691 0.99969342 0.99962529 0.99916542
 0.99902917 0.99887588 0.99919097 0.99943794 0.99847562 0.9988333
 0.99905472 0.99913988 0.99931871 0.99936129 0.99893549 0.99869704
 0.99842453 0.99868001 0.99868852 0.9987822  0.9987311  0.99871407
 0.99860336 0.99826272 0.99805834 0.99785395 0.99792208 0.99804982
 0.99797317 0.99797317 0.99778582 0.99749627 0.99751331 0.99758143
 0.99732595 0.99741111 0.99699383 0.99733447 0.99728337 0.99686608
 0.99714712 0.9973515  0.99753885 0.99753034 0.99762402 0.99774324
 0.99781989 0.99765808 0.99739408 0.9974026  0.99723228 0.99737705
 0.99728337 0.99728337 0.99736002 0.99726634 0.99732595 0.99721524
 0.99728337 0.99701937 0.99715563 0.99715563 0.99744518 0.99753034
 0.99747073 0.99765808 0.9978284  0.99726634 0.99724931 0.99776879
 0.99746221 0.9976666  0.9976666  0.99744518 0.99734298 0.99833085
 0.99866298 0.99800724 0.99714712 0.99648286 0.99588674 0.99598041
 0.99563125 0.99595486 0.99626144 0.99601448 0.99456674 0.9947541
 0.99499255 0.99483926 0.9950181  0.99497552 0.99484778 0.99424313
 0.99416649 0.99416649 0.9942772  0.99288908 0.99266766 0.99293166
 0.99248031 0.99312753 0.99269321 0.99307643 0.99286353 0.99319566
 0.99346817 0.99337449 0.99322972 0.99302534 0.99322121 0.99307643
 0.99295721 0.99344262 0.99262508 0.99259953 0.99246327 0.99254844
 0.99265063 0.99288908 0.99288908 0.9930594  0.9933234  0.99340004
 0.99320417 0.99331488 0.99319566 0.99335746 0.99322121 0.99271876
 0.99271024 0.99270172 0.99259102 0.99308495 0.99331488 0.9930083
 0.99285501 0.99289759 0.99276134 0.99259102 0.99266766 0.99221631
 0.99216521 0.99225889 0.99227592 0.99196934 0.99162018 0.99147541
 0.99134767 0.99159463 0.99152651 0.99166276 0.99169683 0.99168831
 0.99175644 0.99178199 0.99161167 0.99165425 0.99170534 0.9915776
 0.9915776  0.99144135 0.99169683 0.99170534 0.99144986 0.99170534
 0.99187567 0.99192676 0.99183308 0.99177347 0.99173941 0.99176496
 0.99170534 0.9917905  0.99178199 0.99144986 0.99147541 0.99142431
 0.99149244 0.99139877]
```

And here is one output array:

```
[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.99449862
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.99731744 0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.99356185
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         1.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.99686608
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.99866298 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.99134767 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.        ]
```

And this is the model I am trying to train the data on (most likely with a bad architecture):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(x.shape[1:]) ,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add (Dense(1 ,activation = 'sigmoid'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y,epochs=20,validation_split=0.20)
```

How I would like the model to train is to see the input and produce an array of 500 values like the output array shown above.
But no matter what shape I try, I get an error like the following:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 500)
```

What shape is the proper shape here and what am I doing wrong with the model architecture?

UPDATE 1:

I also tried reshaping `x` and `y` to:

```
(9766, 1, 500)
(9766, 1, 500)
```

still no luck.

Comment: An LSTM layer expects input shape as [`[batch, timesteps, feature]`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2). So, with the shape `(9766, 1, 500)`, you have 1 timestep with 500 features? Please elaborate more on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Kaveh thank you for your input. I am fairly new at this so apologies if I lack any formal terminology. I am trying to train the model to produce an array of 500 values (Output) by learning certain features from an array of 500 values (Input). That would be one iteration through the network if I am right. And I have 9766 records of Inputs and outputs. This is Also kind of a timeseries data so thats why I chose LSTM. I take it my "Update 1" is also incorrect because it didn't take any errors away.

Comment: You have 9766 samples. Each sample has 500 values. My question is, are these 500 values for each sample **timesteps** or **features**? In the first case, you need to have (9766, 500, 1) input shape, and in the latter, you need to have (9766,1,500). Furthermore, based on the case you have, you need to correct your model architecture.

Comment: Oh they are timesteps. So I'll go with (9766, 500, 1). With that being said, how would you propose I correct my model architecture?

Comment: I am going to post a reasonable architecture in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM layer expects input shape as [batch, timesteps, feature]. So, with the shape (9766, 1, 500), you have one timestep with 500 features. If you have 500 timesteps, your shape should be like `(9766, 500, 1)`.

Here is an example architecture:

```
x = tf.random.uniform((9766,500,1))
y = tf.random.uniform((9766,500,1))


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(x.shape[1:])))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation = 'relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 ,activation = 'sigmoid'))) # You can also remove timedistributed wrapper if you get better result. I supposed you need to have your output values between 0.0 and 1.0
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy']) # Be careful about your chosen metric. 
model.summary()
```

If you check the model summary, you see input and output shape are the same as you expected:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_15 (LSTM)              (None, 500, 128)          66560     
                                                                 
 dropout_13 (Dropout)        (None, 500, 128)          0         
                                                                 
 lstm_16 (LSTM)              (None, 500, 128)          131584    
                                                                 
 dropout_14 (Dropout)        (None, 500, 128)          0         
                                                                 
 lstm_17 (LSTM)              (None, 500, 32)           20608     
                                                                 
 dropout_15 (Dropout)        (None, 500, 32)           0         
                                                                 
 time_distributed_1 (TimeDis  (None, 500, 1)           33        
 tributed)                                                       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 218,785
Trainable params: 218,785
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: That did it. thank you very much. One quick follow up if you wouldn't mind; as `accuracy` is not the best metric to keep track of for regression models, what replacement metric would you prefer?

Comment: @Mahdi_J It depends on your problem. For example, if you have selling data time series, SMAPE or MAPE is a proper metric. Generally, the MSE and MAE are suitable choices for most cases.

Comment: another follow up if you wouldn't mind. The model completed the training just fine. But right after the midpoint of epoch 1, `loss` and `val_loss` turned into `nan`, also when testing manually, the prediction output of the model was just an array full of `nan` values. I think I am doing something wrong because this shouldn't necessarily be a hard problem for the network since the original output data is produced by `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`

Comment: @Mahdi_J You are likely experiencing exploding gradients. It is hard to say exactly what is leading to this issue, however, you can check the possible reasons in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434284/2423278).

Comment: After reading that post, I figured out having mostly 0 values in the output was very problematic, instead I added a very tiny value like 0.0001 where 0 should be. That helped a lot.