# CNN outputs nan Loss after first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was training my CNN model with my data and after i made some adjustments (i changed sigmoid activations into relu on convolutions and added learning rate decay function) i get NAN loss and NAN mae after first epoch. can anyone tell me what should i do?

```py
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
    return 1/(1+(1/math.e)*epoch)*lr

lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
with tpu_strategy.scope():
    modelCNN = tf.keras.Sequential()
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(100, (8, 8), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()) 
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(8, 8), strides=(3, 3)))
    
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(100, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()) 
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D())
    
    modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
    modelCNN.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mae'])

modelCNN.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=96, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), callbacks=[lr_schedule])
```

```
Epoch 1/96 8127/8127 [==============================] - 232s 26ms/step - loss: 64.8304 - mae: 64.8304 - val_loss: nan - val_mae: nan - lr: 0.0100
Epoch 2/96 3448/8127 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: nan - mae: nan
```

**UPDATE #1**
Removing BatchNormalization Layers Fixed the problem , but the mae was decreasing too slow and incosistently. how can i target this problem?

Comment: Did you try lowering the initial learning rate?
ReLU can "blow up" which is way less common for sigmoid activation functions.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry about last message, yes i tried lowering the initial learning rate. i think it was 0.001

Comment: Do you feed the raw inputs (e.g. pixel values) or do you apply some kind of normalization (e.g. simply a minmax norm) ? Try dividing your inputs by 255 while feeding.

Comment: @null i do rescaling. still no effect!

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40050397/8380054).

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering your learning rate. Its very high, and can be a cause for this error.
For large data, a lower lr is better, and you have lots of it.
Normally lr=0.001 is good for most ML tasks, so give it a try.

I also recommend mean_squared_error for the loss, as it will encourage the model to correct bigger mistakes, instead of trying to correct smaller details, but more epochs with mae also works.

```
modelCNN.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae']).
```

Comment: This does not work as i stated in comments